# Compact Node Definition

Tags: linux, centos, puppet

I created a new module for my autofs mounts using defined types so I can specify as many new mounts in my node definitions as needed. So for example my node definition looks like the following:

```
node "backend" {
include autofs
autofs::client {
'home':
mount_name     => 'home',
local_dir      => '*',
mount_options  => '-rw,intr,noatime',
nfs_server     => 'nfs-server',
remote_path    => '/share/home/&',
}
autofs::client {
'opt':
mount_name     => 'opt',
local_dir      => '/opt',
mount_options  => '-rw,intr,noatime',
nfs_server     => 'nfs-server',
remote_path    => '/share/software',
}
```

Is there anyway I can compact my node definition so if I have say 50 different mounts I don't have to have them all listed under my node but instead could have it in a separate include file?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should just define another class and include that, just as you've included autofs. The puppet manual has a page on doing just that.

http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/advanced_puppet_pattern

Comment: Should I store the new class containing this information with the module? I'm really just kind of confused on the heirarchy